# jquery show hide div but onchange it remember it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jquery for a form to choose some options, en when a radio button whas clicked it shows a new div with options, and so on for 4 divs.

example: i click "Spreekwoorden" that opens a div named "niveau" and when i click here a radio button it opens "vraagstelling" and here i click also on a radio button.

Now i don't want this and choose for Woordenschat.
This has to open "niveau" -> "vraagstelling" -> "groep".
But when i do this it remembers my action what i did before and opens all the divs at once and remembers the clicked radio buttons what i clicked before.

How can i achieve that when i change from "onderdeel" that the script don't remember the clicked radio buttons and that i have opened the div before so that the divs appear when i click a radio button again?

I placed the code here:

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/gryjjxct/2/][1]jsfiddle[1]
```

Comment: where are element with id "groepen" and "niveau"??

Comment: Your code is a bit unclear some codes are missing please include at relevant codes

Comment: full code can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/gryjjxct/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bit of jquery - `removeAttr("checked")` - to clear the radio selections each time an option is chosen:

```
 $('input[name=onderdeel]').click(function () {

     if (this.id == "show_groepen") {
         $("input[name=vraagstelling]").removeAttr("checked");
         $("#niveau").hide();
         $("#vraagstelling").hide();
         $("#groepen").show('slow');
     } else {
         $("#groepen").hide('slow');
     }

     if (this.id == "show_niveau") {
         $("input[name=vraagstelling]").removeAttr("checked");
         $("#niveau").hide();
         $("#vraagstelling").hide();
         $("#niveau").show('slow');
     } else {
         $("#niveau").hide('slow');
     }
});
```

Comment: this only clears the radio button i also want that the script don't remember i opend it before when i change "onderdeel"

Comment: Your code in the question is incomplete, but I've taken a best guess at which other divs to hide.

Comment: I know and thats why i placed the full code here:  https://jsfiddle.net/gryjjxct/2/

Answer (score 0):

I did make sme changes to the script.
Now the first 3 options in "onderdeel" works fine.
The last 2 are incorrect because the buttons are already checked.

Also when i go back from the last "woordenschat" to the first "spreekwoorden" it shows me all the divs and i don't know why

What are the codes that i need to make the script works?
When a div is used before like in "woordenschat i want the script works like i have never used it when i go back to "spreekwoorden".

This is my updated version: jsfiddle.net/gryjjxct/4/